# Who am I who my posture will change social stigma?

Tags: riddle, word

I am a peculiar creature.
When I stand still, some people will avoid me.
When I do a handstand, many people who previously avoided me come to me, but few people who come to me will run away.
But, people argue whether I can do a handstand. At least there are people that with all their saneness claim that I never do a handstand. However some other people claim that they see me do a handstand.

Comment: I will see tomorrow if there is another plausible answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this might be:

> **A dog**.
>
>  Some people are scared of dogs and will avoid them. Turning a dog on it's head gives you **God**. Some people who are afraid of dogs come to God. Many people believe that God does not exist.